# De Moivre's Theorem (Trigo)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Prove the trigo identity by using method based on De Moivre's Theorem.

$\sin^6\theta=\frac{1}{32}(10-15\cos2\theta+6\cos4\theta-\cos6\theta)$

My attempt,

Using $z-\frac{1}{z}=2i\sin \theta$

$(2i\sin \theta)^6=(z-\frac{1}{z})^6$

$2^6i^6\sin ^6\theta=z^6+\frac{1}{z^6}-6z^4-\frac{6}{z^4}+15z^2+\frac{15}{z^2}-20$

$64i^6\sin ^6\theta=(z^6+\frac{1}{z^6})-6(z^4+\frac{1}{z^4})+15(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2})=20$

Since $z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}=2i\sin n\theta$

$64i^6\sin ^6\theta=2i\sin 6\theta-6(2i\sin4 \theta)+15(2i \sin2\theta)-20$

$\sin^6\theta=\frac{1}{32}(\sin6\theta-6\sin4\theta+15\sin2\theta-20)$

How to proceed to prove that $\sin^6\theta=\frac{1}{32}(10-15\cos2\theta+6\cos4\theta-\cos6\theta)$?

Comment: Well for example $\sin^2\theta=\frac12(1-\cos(2\theta))$...

Comment: Remark that, since $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, it is possible to write $\sin^6\theta$ as $(1-\cos^2\theta)^3$.

Comment: If you prefer $\cos^6 \theta$, then prove that $\cos^6\theta=\frac{1}{32}(10+15\cos2\theta+6\cos4\theta+\cos6\theta)$.

Comment: @Tom-Tom I've edited my post. Can you guide me from where I stopped?

Comment: @DietrichBurde  I've edited my post. Can you guide me from where I stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\sin x+i\cos x)^6$

$=(\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x))^6=\cos(3\pi-6x)+i\sin(3\pi-3x)$

$=-\cos(6x)+i\sin(3x)$

Expanding the original left hand side, we get

$\Re((\sin x+i\cos x)^6)=32\sin^6 x-48\sin^4 x+18\sin^2x-1$

Thus,

$32\sin^6(x)=-\cos(6x)+48\sin^4(x)+18\sin^2(x)-1$

We have,

$\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$

$\sin^4(x)=(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2})^2=\frac{1}{4}\cos^2(2x)-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)+\frac{1}{4}$

Use this and linearize $\cos^2(2x)$ and you'll get the required answer (as long as I have made no calculation errors)

Comment: Can I know how $\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ come?

Comment: @Mathxx $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=\cos(x)$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Use de Moivre the following way

$$\begin{align}\sin^6{\theta}
&=\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}\right)^6\\
&=\dfrac{e^{6i\theta}-6e^{4i\theta}+15e^{2i\theta}-20+15e^{-2i\theta}-6e^{-4i\theta}+e^{-6i\theta}}{-64}\\
&=\frac{\cos{6\theta}-6\cos{4\theta}+15\cos{2\theta}-10}{-32}\\
&=\frac{-\cos{6\theta}+6\cos{4\theta}-15\cos{2\theta}+10}{32}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is : $$2\cos (n\theta)=z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}$$ but you put $2i\sin (n\theta)$ instead