# De Moivre's Theorem (Trigonometry)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How to prove that $\cos^4 \theta+\sin ^4\theta=\frac{1}{4}(\cos4\theta+3)$ by using De Moivre's Theorem?

I know that $(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n=\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta$, but how to apply this question to this theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(\cos x + i\sin x)^4=\cos 4x + i\sin 4x$

Expanding the left side, we have the real part equal to:

$\Re((\cos x+i \sin x)^4)= \sin^4 x+\cos^4 x-6\sin^2 x\cos^2 x$

Thus,

$\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x=\cos 4x+6\sin^2 x\cos^2 x$

$=\cos4x+6 (\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{2})^2$

$=\cos 4x+\frac{3}{2}\sin^2 2x$

$=\cos 4x+\frac{3}{2}(\frac{1-\cos 4x}{2})$

$\cos4x+\frac{3}{4}-\frac{3}{4}\cos4x$

Finally, we write it in the form:

$\sin^4 x+\cos^4x=\frac{1}{4}(\cos 4x+3)$

Comment: How 6 become 3/2?

Comment: The $\frac{1}{2}$ inside when squared is $\frac{1}{4}$. Multiplying this by $6$ and simplifying, you get $\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: $\sin^6x=\frac{1}{32}(10-15\cos2x+6\cos4x-\cos6x$ is this question same way with that one?

Comment: Yeah, this method can always be used (you'lll have to write the $\cos ^6x$ in terms of $\sin^x$ though). However, in the case where you have only one trigonometric function (only $\sin x$ here), I recommend you use $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ if it's allowed.

Comment: I wonder can you provide one sample answer for me without using the exponential? Thanks

Comment: Make a separate question. I can't answer two questions here.

Comment: Here it is. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299453/de-moivres-theorem-trigo

Comment: I've put the link up there

Answer (score 2):

use the facts $2\cos t = e^{it} + e^{-it}, \, 2i\sin t = e^{it} - e^{-it}$ to get

$$\begin{align} 2^4(\cos^4 t + \sin^4 t) &= (e^{it} + e^{-it})^4 + (e^{it} -e^{-it})^4 \\
&=e^{4it}+4e^{2it} + 6 + 4e^{-2it}+e^{-4it}+  \left(e^{4it}-4e^{2it} + 6 - 4e^{-2it}+e^{-4it}\right)\\
&=2\left((e^{4it} + e^{-4it}) + 6\right)\\
&=2\left(2\cos 4t + 6\right)\end{align}$$

therefore $$ \cos^4 t + \sin^4 t = \frac14\left(\cos 4t + 3\right) $$

Answer (score 0):

$\cos(4\theta)$ is the real part of $(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)^4$. By developping this expression and identifying its real part, you should find the result.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to turn powers if $\sin$ and $\cos$ into multiple angles is to use the identites $$2\cos\theta=z+\frac1z$$ and $$2i\sin\theta=z-\frac1z$$

Expand these to the relevant power, in this case 4, using Pascal'sTriangle, and group the resulting terms together. Then apply the associated identites $$2\cos (n\theta)=z^n+\frac {1}{z^n}$$ and $$2i\sin (n\theta)=z^n-\frac {1}{z^n}$$

Answer (score 0):

For fun, with ‘pure’ trigonometry – just Pythagoras and duplication formulae:

\begin{align*}\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta&=(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)^2-2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta=1-\frac12\sin^22\theta\\
& =1-\frac14(1-\cos4\theta )=\frac{3+\cos 4\theta }{4} \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, a pretty unusual way to show it, using differential equations.
Consider $f:\theta\mapsto\sin^4\theta+\cos^4\theta-\frac34$. We have
$$f'(\theta)=4\sin^3\theta\cos\theta-4\cos^3\theta\sin\theta$$ and
$$f''(\theta)=-4\sin^4\theta+12\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta-4\cos^4\theta+12\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta.$$ 
Since $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$, we can write $\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta=\sin^2\theta-\cos^4\theta$ or $\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta=\cos^2\theta-\sin^4\theta$, this gives $f''(\theta)=-16\sin^4\theta-16\cos^4\theta+12=-16f(\theta)$. Since $f(0)=\frac14$ and $f'(0)=0$, it follows that the result is $f(\theta)=\frac14\cos4\theta$.

Comment: Impressive . I'm learning a new thing again